# How to set values in ItemPreparedStatementSetter for one to many mapping

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use `JdbcBatchItemWriter` for a domain object `RemittanceClaimVO` . `RemittanceClaimVO` has a `List` of another domain object , `ClaimVO` .

```
public class RemittanceClaimVO {

private long remitId;
private List<ClaimVO> claims = new ArrayList<ClaimVO>();

//setter and getters
}
```

So for each remit id, there would be multiple claims and I wish to use single batch statement to insert all rows.

With plain jdbc, I used to write this object by putting values in batches like below ,

```
ist<ClaimVO> claims = remittanceClaimVO.getClaims();
            if(claims != null && !claims.isEmpty()){
            for(ClaimVO claim:claims){
                int counter = 1 ;
                stmt.setLong(counter++, remittanceClaimVO.getRemitId());
                stmt.setLong(counter++, claim.getClaimId());

                stmt.addBatch();
            }
            }

            stmt.executeBatch();
```

I am not sure how to achieve same in Spring Batch by using `ItemPreparedStatementSetter`.

I have tried similar loop as above in `setValues` method but values not getting set.

```
@Override
    public void setValues(RemittanceClaimVO remittanceClaimVO, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

        List<ClaimVO> claims = remittanceClaimVO.getClaims();

        for(ClaimVO claim:claims){
            int counter = 1 ;
            ps.setLong(counter++, remittanceClaimVO.getRemitId());
            ps.setLong(counter++, claim.getClaimId());

    }

    }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493140/how-to-fetch-string-from-setvalues-method-of-preparedstatementsetter/16921579#comment65543638_16921579) seems another related question.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a composite item writer here?  One for the parent and one for the children?

Comment: I solved issue by writing custom writer using `JdbcTemplate and BatchPreparedStatementSetter`. Since I was using in built writer so thought to use `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` .